# Spring bean constructor-arg property resolution internally

Tags: java, spring

I am using these classes:

**Coach.java**

```
public interface Coach {
    void getDailyWorkout();
    String getName();
    String getExperience();
}
```

**TrackCoach.java**

```
public class TrackCoach implements Coach {

    private String name;
    private String experience;

    public TrackCoach(String name, int num, String experience) {
        this.name = name;
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public void getDailyWorkout() {
        System.out.println("Run 5k on track");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TrackCoach{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", experience='" + experience + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**appContext.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="coach4" class="com.prakhar.TrackCoach">
        <constructor-arg value="7 years"/>
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="Mr. Track #4"/>
        <constructor-arg name="num" value="10"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I am trying to get the `coach4` bean, I am getting an error of **UnsatisfiedDependencyException** type. I am not able to understand how Spring resolves constructor arguments, the actual steps / flow. Its like a magic to me, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. For example, if we remove second `constructor-arg`'s `name` property, it will be working fine.

Could anyone please tell me how Spring resolves constructor arguments internally? I am using Spring 5.2.3.

Comment: try `<constructor-arg name="experience" value="7 years"/>`

Comment: What is your purpose for using a `beans.xml`? I haven't used one in about 5 years because the newer options are much better (and this is a great example of why).

Comment: The purpose is to understand Spring framework better, I won't be able to crack twisted questions of some exam I am appearing for, if I don't understand whats happening behind the scenes. Educational purpose, basically.

Answer (score 0):

In your case order matters:

```xml
<bean id="coach4" class="com.prakhar.TrackCoach">
    <constructor-arg value="7 years"/>
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="Mr. Track #4"/>
    <constructor-arg name="num" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

```java
public TrackCoach(String name, int num, String experience) {
```

So, the first constructor-arg is interpreted as name, because it's the first argument of constructor in **TrackerCoach** class.
Then you have second constructor-arg, which have name attribute, which has the value of name, because of this conflict happens. You have 2 args which match to name constructor arg and 0 which match to **experience**.
When you remove name attribute in XML, *7 years* goas as name *Mr. Track #4* goas as experience and 10 goas as num.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but the 2nd argument is an integer, and if we remove name attribute, shouldn't I get a NumberFormatException, as it should be trying to convert `Mr. Track #4` to an integer?

Comment: But you still have constructor-arg with name **num**. That's why spring still will use that constructor-arg for num, and others in the order they are listed.

Answer (score 0):

**The constructor-arg element within the bean element is used to set the property value thru constructor injection**.

In your case, your Object (TrackCoach) only has two properties and three constructor arguments. The reason it works when you remove the second name property is because the defaults become two which match the object properties and it then gets matched the two propeties of the TrackCoach object.  There is no property called num, therefore the spring container will blow up with an Exception.

**In a nutshell, your object properties have to match your constructor arguments.**

Comment: Actually, I rewritten my code and changed num to age on my machine. Made it a property. Still works the same.

Comment: add the third property to your TrackCoach object.